# PushState in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to ask.

I have created an autoload scroll
but when it scrolls and there is new article, the title bar and url don't change.

can anyone help me?

I make javascript in view like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var track_page = 1; 
var loading  = false;
//var idarticle = <?php //echo $content['idartikel']?>;
var idarticle = document.getElementById('idarticle').value;
var idkanal = <?php echo $content['idkanal']?>; 
var row = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        track_page++;
        row++;
        load_contents(track_page,idarticle,idkanal,row);
        tes(track_page,idarticle,idkanal,row);
    }
});

function load_contents(track_page,idarticle,idkanal,row){
  if(loading == false){
    loading = true;  
    $('.loading-info').show();  
    $.post( "http://localhost/staging-casa2/article/more/",
      {page:track_page,idkanal:idkanal,idartikel:idarticle,startrow:row},
      function(data){
        loading = false; 
        if(data.trim().length == 0 || track_page >= 10){
          $('.loading-info').html("");
          return;
      }
      $('.loading-info').hide(); 


        $("#more_article").append(data); 

    }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
      alert(thrownError); 
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56734479/8566549) on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56731374/8566549)?

Comment: yes, and my other question is solved